# Wordpress XMLRPC Advanced Custom Fields, Realtionship Field

Tags: python, wordpress, post, xml-rpc

I want to create new Wordpress posts with XMLRPC, I was able to edit the Realtionship field with his id only, I want to call the field with his title or other taxonomies.

This is my code in python:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts

client = Client(my_website, my_username, my_password)

newPost = WordPressPost()
newPost.title = 'test'
newPost.content = 'test content'
newPost.custom_fields = [{'key': 'trailer', 'value' : 'test'}, {'key': 'the_key', 'value': 'the_value'}]
client.call(posts.NewPost(newPost))
```

the trailer field works, but, the Relationship field needs the id of the post I want to link.